# Kids' book about boys finding a disc from a planet called "Eyopee"

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this children's book in 1964 or 1965.

In the novel in question, one or two young boys find a metal disc that he or they hammer on to the nose of a backyard spaceship he or they built, giving it the ability to exit Earth's atmosphere. He or they are accompanied into space by an extraterrestrial being who lost the metal disc on Earth. As best as I can recall the alien being was from the (fictional) planet "Eyopee."

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  You might want to check the story identification tag to see if there are any points that might jog your memory on some additional facts that might help identify your novel: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: @Lawrence  Eyopee sounds a lot like Eopee in Rusty's Space Ship, so it looks like Valorum's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 18):

Could this be [Rusty's Space Ship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007E12E2) (1957) by Evelyn Sibley Lampman?

> There was no way for Rusty Adams to know that the **shiny metal disc** he had found at the city dump and used on his play space ship in the garage, was actually the flying saucer of the Mighty Gwump of **Eopee** in Adromeda Galaxy. When tiny Tiphia, Gwump's messenger, arrived to claim it, Rusty and his playmate Susan Northrup found themselves taking an unexpected trip to all of the planets, except Neptune and Plato. Rusty and Susan save Tiphia from attack by ants and other hazards as he vainly tries to find the moon, Eopee. It's Rusty who realizes finally that Tiphia is simply in the wrong galaxy. This is a Baedeker of Outer Space.

Comment: ...The planet Plato? lol. Wonder if that's a typo (on the site).

Comment: I suspect it's a typo in the review