# 60's book about a boy who builds a spaceship from cardboard in garage

Tags: story-identification

The boy builds this spaceship and a dog like a creature appears and makes the ship real.  They take off on amazing adventures.  I read this in the very early '60s and have never forgotten it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/childrens-novel-three-children-plus-dog-travel-to-the-moon-in-pretend-space

Answer (score 8):

This is [*Rusty's Space Ship* by Evelyn Lampman](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11390330-rusty-s-space-ship). The dog-like creature actually looks somewhat like a kangaroo; it's an extraterrestrial named "Tiphia". And the boy and girl who go along with the ride, also take an actual dog with them. P.S. The spaceship is made of scraps of wood. The boy finds a thin disk of metal in a junkyard and hammers it on the nose of his ship. Tiphia comes looking for it -- the disk is actually *his* spaceship.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202126/kids-book-about-boys-finding-a-disc-from-a-planet-called-eyopee/202129#202129

Comment: Confirmed in the question, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214674/book-about-space-zoo-collectors

Comment: But it's not accepted there... :-(