# kids’ book from the 1950s/early ‘60s about a boy who built a spaceship out of a box and took his dog into space

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Children’s book, likely written in later ‘50s or early ‘60s featuring a young boy builds space ship in yard ( garage?) from cardboard box.

- His dog may talk, may be an alien.
- He takes his dog into space.
- Likely black/white illustrations.

Comment: This is very terse. You could improve this question considerably by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: *Space Boy and his Dog* is too late, being 2015

Answer (score 3):

This could be *Rusty's Space Ship* By Evelyn Shipley Lampman, 1957.

Two kids, Rusty and Susan, build a play spaceship out of junk.  But a mysterious person wants their ship, who turns out of be a lizard shaped alien named Tiphia.

Anyway, most of the plot involves, Tiphia, the kids, and their dog travelling around the solar system in Rusty's play spaceship powered by Tiphia's own spaceship.

It is mentioned in other answers:

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235355#235355[1]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235355#235355%5B1%5D)

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202126/kids-book-about-boys-finding-a-disc-from-a-planet-called-eyopee/202129#202129[2]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202126/kids-book-about-boys-finding-a-disc-from-a-planet-called-eyopee/202129#202129%5B2%5D)

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214382/60s-book-about-a-boy-who-builds-a-spaceship-from-cardboard-in-garage/214384#214384[3]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214382/60s-book-about-a-boy-who-builds-a-spaceship-from-cardboard-in-garage/214384#214384%5B3%5D)

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/childrens-novel-three-children-plus-dog-travel-to-the-moon-in-pretend-space/145518#145518[4]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/childrens-novel-three-children-plus-dog-travel-to-the-moon-in-pretend-space/145518#145518%5B4%5D)

And my answer to this question about interstellar navigation wonders whether Tripetha ever managed to find his home world.

[https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180161/finding-earth-on-a-star-map/180214#180214%5B1%5D[5]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180161/finding-earth-on-a-star-map/180214#180214%5B1%5D%5B5%5D)

Comment: Tiphia is the alien.